# What happens if a state omits a major party candidate from their presidential ballot

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, ballot

This question is inspired by [this other question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/96991/can-states-refuse-to-put-a-candidate-on-a-ballot).

Suppose a state determines that a major party candidate should not be on their presidential general election ballot, perhaps because they believe it would be in violation of the 14th Amendment. What should they do instead for that party?

Would they omit the party entirely? This effectively hands their electors to the other major party, since a third party candidate has virtually no chance of being elected, and disenfranchises voters who wanted to vote for this party.

Would they keep the party on the ballot, and name their own candidate in place of the one the party chose?

Or would the ballots simply say something like "Electors for X Party" without a candidate name, since that's technically what you're always voting for. But if that's done, what's the point of leaving the candidate off the ballot? The electors still choose who to vote for in the Electoral College, and the voters know who they'll select in "X Party". Would removal of the candidate also direct the electors not to vote for them?

Since the details of voting are governed at the state level, I imagine there may be a variety of solutions. Have they been codified in state laws, or would we be in unprecedented and unforeseen circumstances should this occur (which is a distinct possibility, as there are now court cases in several states challenging Trump's eligibility)?

Comment: Kind of a hypothetical / speculative Q, IMHO, given the lack of precedent. We might find out in a year or so.

Comment: @Fizz That's what I'm wondering -- is it totally uncharted, or have state legislatures made arrangements for it in their election laws?

Answer (score 1):

> **Question:**
>
> What happens if a state omits a major party candidate from their presidential ballot.

That is exactly what the **[14th Amendment section 3 of the US Constitution](https://constitution.findlaw.com/amendment14/annotation15.html)** calls for the states to do.

The only thing people on both sides of this discussion agree upon is it almost certainly means the supreme court would have to weigh in.   To have some states excluding a major party's candidate while others did not is unthinkable.  The precedent is too dangerous without a supreme court decision making a final uniform decision for the nation.

Comment: It's not unthinkable. It's exactly what happened to Abraham Lincoln in 1860. Let's just say political stability deteriorated shortly thereafter.

Comment: @SurpriseDog,   **2 thoughts**.   (1) Wasn't exactly similar, much less exactly the same. The courts and US Constitution were not used to exclude Lincoln from the Ballot in 1860,.   Lincoln failed to meet the state's Ballot access requirements due to lack of grass root support and party representation in 10  Southern states.   Which still happens today generally to 3rd party candidates.   (2)There are a lot of things which occurred  in 1860 which are unthinkable today.

Comment: @SupriseDog,   I would also add that it was the Kansas entering the Union as a free state,  Jan 29, 1861.  Which blew apart the pro slave equilibrium in Congress which was the more influential event necessitating the "deterioration"  which followed from the vantage of pro-slave states.   That's what made slavery politically unsustainable.   The Southern voting block no longer had the votes to protect the institution. The country had anti slave president's prior to Lincoln.  Lincoln was actually a fairly moderate on the topic compared to the other Republican Candidates in 1860.

Comment: "The only thing people on both sides of this discussion agree upon is it almost certainly means the supreme court would have to weigh in." SCOTUS may weigh in, but it certainly doesn't have to and hasn't weighed in on enforcement of Section 3 of the 14th Amendment for other offices. "To have some states excluding a major party's candidate while others did not is unthinkable." The candidates on the ballot are different on different state ballots in essentially all modern Presidential elections. It is hardly unthinkable. And, if a state excluding Trump was a blue state, it wouldn't even matter.

Comment: Uniformity is possible even if SCOTUS does not weigh in, however. Under the legal doctrine of collateral estoppel, if Trump is declared ineligible to run in a final court judgment in any state, the determination that he was ineligible would be binding on him in litigation over his eligibility in every other U.S. state. And, keep in mind, that if Trump's exclusion keeps him off the ballot in primary season (where differing state primary/caucus ballots are common as the long primary/caucus process evolves anyway) it wouldn't deny ballot access to a non-Trump GOP candidate anywhere.

Comment: @ohwilleke,  14-3 has never been used before against a Presidential candidate, much less one from the two major parties.   That's what makes this action more questionable, and it's what will necessitate a supreme court ruling,  according to parties on both sides of the issue.  And again,  it's not true a major candidate is excluded from some ballots in every election, nor most Presidential elections.   When it occurs it's typically a 3rd party candidate and it's due to failing to meet state ballot access requirements not a court exclusion and not due to U.S. Constitutional concerns.

Comment: @ohwilleke,  If a candidate is excluded **under the constitution** in one state,  he arguable should be excluded from all, or not.   That's why the supreme court needs to be involved here.   Colorado and Minnesota can't both hear the same argument and come out with different rulings.   One has to be right, and the other has to be wrong; and that's the purpose of the supreme court to decide.

Comment: @JMS I agree that is hasn't been used before against a Presidential candidate (the only plausible case where it could have been used was against Eugene Debs in 1920 who didn't make it onto the ballot in every state for other reasons anyway, probably simply because no one brought it up, he was legally disenfranchised at the time which would have disqualified him under many state ballot access laws). But major party candidates were frequently disqualified below the Presidential level in the Reconstruction era. The good thing about law is the precedents from less cases guide us.

Comment: @JMS The Supreme Court can be involved. But it doesn't have to. There are literally hundreds of legal issues upon which contradictory interpretation of federal law including the U.S. Constitution are applied in different states. Collateral estoppel could change that analysis, but it isn't even all that unusual for CO and MN to interpret a particular U.S. Constitution provision in contrary ways. SCOTUS might decide, with its public reputation plummeting that this issue is too hot to handle and simply deny certiorari on all attempts to appeal to it. This wouldn't be particularly unusual.

Comment: @ohwilleke,    We should hear about the Colorado case results before the end of next week.   I have my popcorn ready.  I agree they don't have to get involved.  But as I've said lawyers on both sides of this issue at least half of whom know less about this than myself,  all believe it's going to end up there.

Comment: @JMS We will hear about the Colorado case soon, but probably not that soon. Closing arguments are on November 15, 2023. Judge Wallace almost certainly won't deliver a ruling from the bench. Everyone knows that this is a big deal case and Judge Wallace will craft a carefully written and polished written opinion, probably sometime between the week after next and Thanksgiving. From there, there is a direct appeal of right to the Colorado Supreme Court, which is almost certain to occur no matter who wins (but Judge Wallace's findings of fact will still bind the Colo. Supreme Court and SCOTUS).

Comment: +1  I read Wallace was going to hear arguments for 1 week and then deliberate for 1 week.  The case began Oct 31,  so I extrapolated.  Good information on our part.  thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The National Association of Secretaries of State has published a summary of [State laws regarding presidential ballot access for the General Election](https://www.nass.org/sites/default/files/surveys/2020-07/research-ballot-access-president-Jan20_0.pdf), as of January 2020.

A common statement regarding access is —

> A presidential candidate nominated by a political party may be placed on the general election ballot.

Though some add "recognized", "qualified", "major or minor", etc., in reference to "political party".

Given that no changes are made to any states' laws, the name of whoever is nominated will be on the ballot.

Using Colorado as an example —

This is a portion of a sample ballot from Colorado for the 2020 General Election.

[image: Portion of the 2020 General Election ballot for Colorado]

[[Clear Creek County, CO 2020 Sample Ballot](https://co.clear-creek.co.us/DocumentCenter/View/11423/005-ISWM?bidId=)]

The candidates for President and Vice President are paired. To prevent a state-disqualified presidential candidate from appearing while allowing a qualified vice presidential candidate to appear would require a change in the law to allow separate (unpaired) voting. Otherwise, a voter choosing the qualified vice presidential candidate would be denied any choice for the presidential candidate. Furthermore, only the name of the candidate nominated by a political party can be placed on the general election ballot.

Also note that under Colorado law for the general election, it appears that only presidential electors are nominated by political parties and the names of the candidates for president and vice president are simply added to the party certificate of nomination.

[C.R.S. Title 1 Elections](https://www.sos.state.co.us/pubs/info_center/laws/Title1/Title1Article4.html#a1-4-1001)
Article 4 Elections - access to ballot by candidates

> **1-4-701. Party nominations to be made by convention.**
>
> (1) Any convention of delegates of a political party or any committee authorized by resolution of the convention may nominate candidates ... for presidential electors and also may select delegates to national political conventions.
>
> (2) ...
> (d) In the case of presidential electors, the names of the candidates for president and vice president may be added to the name of the political party in the certificate of nomination.

Thus, there appears to be no way to prevent a state-disqualified presidential candidate from appearing on the general election ballot; nor to prevent the presidential electors from choosing that candidate. However, there is the possibility that the governor might refuse to sign the Electoral College vote count for the state-disqualified presidential candidate before transmission to the Archivist for presentation to Congress.

Comment: "Given that no changes are made to any states' laws, the name of whoever is nominated will be on the ballot." If the issue were ballot access rather than qualification for the office, that might be true, but when the issue is as it is here, qualification for the office, this is almost certainly an inaccurate statement of the status quo of state law.